# Ajax post to php file not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is one of my first ajax programs. I don't know why my `$username`variable is remaining undefined. In the `username_availability.php` file. This is my Jquery code:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', "#username", function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../database/username_availability.php",
            data: {username:$('#username').val()}
        });
        var url = 'database/username_availability.php';
        $('#username_check').html('loading…').load(url);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

And this is my php file:

```
include_once "../my_classes/form/connection.php";
$connection = new \mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if (!$connection) die ('Connection failed');
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$username = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
print_r($username);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);
foreach ($result as $results=>$i)
echo $results;
```

I am still getting undefined index on the `$username = ($_POST['username']);`line.

Comment: Your AJAX call is sending down `text`, not `username`, as the variable. To fix that particular issue, you'd refer to `$_POST['text']` in your PHP file.

Comment: That code does not make sense, why are you posting and also doing a GET to the same resource? Do you realize the GET is not sending a username? Do you think the Ajax call and the load() method are related somehow?

Comment: Upvoted to counter the downvotes. Don't be a hater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change in your ajax call:

```
 data: {text:$('#username').val()}
 -------^^^^
```

With this

```
 data: {"username":$('#username').val()}
```

Comment: I changed the `data: {text:$('#username').val()}` to `data: {username:$('#username').val()}` but i am still getting undefined index on  `$username = ($_POST['username']);` line.

Comment: Are you sure you have in your html an `<input type="text" id="username">` ? Take care with the quotes, in my answer I put `"username"` in quotes as you can see

Comment: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="eg. Maria"> this is my html. I am sure.

Comment: Your problem is in your second call. When you make `.load(url)` you are making a GET request that doesn't send parameters. Your ajax call is fine, your second load() call is wrong. What do you need?

Comment: I need to check if the username is available and the just write if the username is available or not in the #username_check div. My username_availability.php is not ready yet. I know it.

Comment: You need to remove this code: `var url = 'database/username_availability.php'; $('#username_check').html('loading…').load(url);` Why you need this?

Comment: I actually i need this `var url = 'database/username_availability.php';
            $('#username_check').load(url);` to `echo 'This username is available';` I am realy new to jquery actually.

Comment: You need another way to display that message. Maybe you need another file as `var url = 'database/username_availability_showtext.php';` and here you put the php code to show the text

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will do it this way.

Comment: Technically a key shouldn't have quotes in js

Comment: Not neccessary in this case, but quotes avoid you to write reserved words and dashed double words as `two-words` that's not allowed without quotes

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax file you are calling the username "text", not "username" but then in the PHP you are looking for the "username" index in the POST array.

This is because in the ajax call you have to NAME the data AND assign it like this:

```
 data: {username:$('#username').val()}
```

alternately you could change your php to this:

```
$username = ($_POST['text']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set value to variable, just like

```
var username = $('#username').val();
data: { 'username' : username }
```

And now it looks much better

Answer (score 1):

Your post data:

```
 data: {text:$('#username').val()}
```

As key you send `text`

On server you can get $_POST['text']

Or

You can change 'text' to 'username'